# Adding a space character (" ") 2 character spaces after a period character (".")?

Tags: python-3.x

We have a legacy system that is exporting reports as .txt files, but in almost all instances when a date is supplied, it is after a currency denomination, and looks like this example:
`25.0002/14/18 (25 bucks on feb 14th)` or `287.4312/08/17`.

Is there an easy way to parse for `.` and add a space character two spaces to the right to separate the string in Python? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below would add a space between the currency and the data given a string.

```
import re 
my_file_text = "This is some text 287.4312/08/17"
new_text = re.sub("(\d+\.\d{2})(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})", r"\1 \2", my_file_text)
print(new_text)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'This is some text 287.43 12/08/17'
```

**REGEX**

`(\d+\.\d{2})`: This part of the regex captures the currency in it's own group, it assumes that it will have any number of digits (>1) before the `.` and then only two digits after, so something like (1000.25) would be captured correctly, while (1000.205) and (.25) won't.

`(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})`: This part captures the date, it assumes that the day, month and year portion of the dates will always be represented using two digits each and separated by a /.

Comment: Try to add some explanation of  how your regex works. Just blindly pasting a regex might not help the OP

Comment: Thank you! Please forgive my ignorance, I am still very new. The second argument in the re.findall is defined as literal, no? would I need to define each currency/date pair in a given file for that to work correctly?

Comment: @Ryan I have updated the answer to suit your needs, just load the text into a single variable and pass it to the function.

Comment: Ahmed, Thank you very much!! Seems to work very very well!

Comment: Glad I could help Ryan, thank you. 

P.S If you could mark the answer as accepted for others, I would be glad.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have selected!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more efficient methods, but an easy way could be:

```
def fix(string):
    if '.' in string:
        part_1, part_2 = string.split('.')
        part_2_fixed = part_2[:2] + ' ' + part_2[2:]
        string = part_1 + '.' + part_2_fixed
    return string
```

```
In [1]: string = '25.0002/14/18'
In [2]: fix(string)                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2]: '25.00 02/14/18'
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not after efficiency! Sadly, I encounter "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" > because this "instance" of currency/date occurs quite a bit in the .txt file. I'm still very new to Python, so I will attempt to hack it together!

Comment: Ah I see, what is an example chunk of this text file? You could first split it up into parts that contain these 'xx.xxxx/xx/xx' strings then run this function on them